# No posts on front page

Tags: frontpage

I've already looked for the way to solve my problem but never found any.

The problem: No posts show on my frontpage. I have these settings:
Settings > Reading > Your homepage displays >  A static page (select below) > Homepage: Home, Posts page: Blog.

The content of the homepage shows correctly but under that there are no posts. The Blog page works correctly alone but those posts won't show on the frontpage.

Where's the problem? Please help!

PS: There's no plugin conflict. I've already checked that.

[image]

Comment: If you select a static page as your homepage then that’s what you’re going to get. not posts. If you want posts on your static front page regardless then you’re going to need to use a theme that does this. WordPress itself does not display any posts when you set the homepage to a static page.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Looks I misuderstood this type of setting.

Answer (score -1):

You don't say if you are on wordpress.com or self-hosted, or which theme you are using. Does it help to look at Wordpress display posts shortcode and put `[display-posts]` into your page content?

https://en.support.wordpress.com/display-posts-shortcode/

If you are self-hosting and your theme supports it (most do), the Display Posts plugin enables and extends this function to give you greater control: https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/

Comment: A comment suggesting why this is a bad answer and your answer would be helpful :) If the OP doesn't say which theme (or even wp.com vs. self-hosted) it's hard to do more than suggest things that may work.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! It just looks like I misunderstood the use of frontpage settings. I'm sorry for taking your time.

Comment: You're welcome, temporarily I have enabled the Display Posts plugin at a site I just barely put together, https://www.learnwithmoocs.com/. Assuming you are self-hosted, and your theme isn't too weird, it should work, it does on my demo for you.

Comment: Also since you look like you are new to Stack Exchange, check out this doc :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers